# How to create a dummy variable of type folly::Future<bool>?

Tags: c++, folly

So in the below code it can be observed that based on the Boolean variable `flag`. In the `folly::collect` operation we add or skip doing the `std::move(cleanupFuture)` operation.

Looking a way to avoid redundant code piece of the `folly::collect`?

I was thinking of using `folly::Unit` but not sure how it would be compatible as return type of `cleanupFuture` is a `folly::Future<bool>`

Logic:

```
  if (flag) {
    return folly::collect(
              std::move(abortFuture))
        .via(folly::CPUExecutor().get())
        .thenValue([](auto&& /* unused */) {});
  }

  return folly::collect(
             std::move(cleanupFuture),
             std::move(abortFuture))
      .via(folly::getGlobalCPUExecutor().get())
      .thenValue([](auto&& /* unused */) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

flag ? std::move(cleanupFuture) : folly::makeFuture(true)